# API REST post hash credentials and make GET, DELETE or PUT request

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, phalcon

I'm working with this [Phalcon PHP API HMAC](https://github.com/jeteokeeffe/php-hmac-rest-api) framework and I have a little question.

I declared a GET route in routes.php and Im trying to make a request from [client-connect.php](https://github.com/jeteokeeffe/php-hmac-rest-api/blob/master/client-connect.php) (a simple CURL script to make requests).

That's how the client looks like:

```
$privateKey = '593fe6ed77014f9502761028801aa376f141916bd26b1b3f0271b5ec3135b989';

$time = time();
$id = 1;

$data = [
    'name' => 'bob',
];


$message = buildMessage($time, $id, $data);

$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $message, $privateKey);
$headers = ['API_ID: ' . $id, 'API_TIME: ' . $time, 'API_HASH: ' . $hash];


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
```

When I make a post request, all works ok, but when I try to make a GET, PUT or DELETE request (I just uncomment the line commented in client), it returns me an error:

```
Request: 
DELETE /nodes/mikrotik HTTP/1.1
Host: vpn.wibee.com
Accept: */*
API_ID: 1
API_TIME: 1446031137
API_HASH: 4d0852239859da5e90270b3f7dfd2167f6e5153ca83a9c5896ee262e41b19674
Content-Length: 508
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------e71b5fd144802749


Response:
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2015 11:18:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

Access denied
```

I think it's posible im missing something (something related with authentication). Any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you declared routes to controller with methods delete/put/get?

Comment: @yergo yes, actually I solved PUT, DELETE request. I'm just having troubles with GET request.

Comment: I would investigate [this line](https://github.com/jeteokeeffe/php-hmac-rest-api/blob/master/app/library/events/api/HmacAuthenticate.php#L71). Maybe you are resetting $this->_maxRequestDelay giving you too small amount of time to work with API

Comment: @yergo not working... I'm only having problems with the GET request. POST, PUT, DELETE... all working. It seems the client link](https://github.com/jeteokeeffe/php-hmac-rest-api/blob/master/client-connect.php) send all other request but not GET. The main developer says it works for him and the the code looks like its stable and not bugy. What's wrong there? : ´ (

Comment: Original client sends all requests including GET. I would blame that there is too much or improper options in curlopt set when you are using your client implementation with other methods than POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try it. In original implementation of client app you have such a part:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
switch($method) {
    case 'POST':
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        break;
    case 'GET':
        break;
    default:
        $data = http_build_query($data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        break;
}
```

And your implementation is quite different. Once you are using POST method, functionality surprisingly work even with `($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE)`. But Once using all other requests, you are running into troubles. It's because your implementation of GET does a few things it should not:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

this is not correct for making GET requests with CURL. It surprisingly works, but you are receiving access denied. It is probably because authentication data, are not properly iterpreted on server side.

Also other methods will have some troubles to work, because you are mising this part of original code:

```
$data = http_build_query($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

My best solution wold be to advise you, to try to use existing code sample instead of rewriting it by hand in buggy way. Extending that code for your use should not be complicated, especially if you are running it from shell.